# facebook unable to load/work properly in linux

Tags: fedora, firefox

I am facing problem with a facebook on linux these days, but when i switch back to windows (windows 7)it works absolutely fine.

I am using fedora 14, 64 bit  machine with Mozilla Firefox 3.6.24. Even i tried to open facebook in opera browser the problem remains same.

Problems seen yet are:

1. After login, the first page appears is not loading fully to see more stories.
2. chat window is not appearing
3. Any picture is not opening on clicking over it.
4. Whenever i click on like button, it does not work.

I even tried :
yum update firefox

No Packages marked for Update

Can anybody tell me what wrong is going on?

Comment: A facebook Unix / GNU Linux user? Who would've thought ;-)

Comment: I've noticed the same behavior on my machine on Chromium. Strange..

Comment: Does the same problem happen when using the same version of the same browser in the Windows install? This is more likely a browser issue and not an OS issue. Other than checking for the OS through the User-Agent and doing different things, there aren't that many ways an AJAX site can work differently across Windows and GNU/Linux

Comment: Can you try with a more recent version of Firefox on a more recent distro? Fedora 14 and Firefox 3.6.24 are quite old.

Comment: It's also time for a more recent version of Fedora.

Comment: That's normal, browser compatibility is difficult to archieve.

Comment: Facebook works properly for me (Firefox 15.0

Answer (score 1):

FireFox 3 is old and busted, I recently battled with it in a site rewrite. There is quite a few HTML5/CSS3 things that are not fully or properly implemented. FB implements cutting edge web technologies such as HTML5 and CSS3.

I recommend building from source to get closer to a version near 10.0 or better.

Answer (score 0):

I use Mageia2 64-bit with Firefox 10.0.5 and everything works perfectly. I am also using the latest Adobe version of their Flash player. So I would agree that the issue is with your browser (old) or, since you haven't stated, your version of Flash player (since Facebook is heavily flash oriented).